# Getting the right Search bar

Tags: android, searchbar

Right now I am using Widget.AppCompat.SearchView to get a search bar that looks and can be adjusted as explained in this [article](http://www.jayway.com/2014/06/02/android-theming-the-actionbar/)

But I want something more like this but with my own color scheme.[image]

Do I need to use another widget? And if so which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need `Theme.AppCompact.Light` for Bright colors.

in `res/values/themes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

or this is for change color of Text (Search Text) ;
in : `res/values/themes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar title text -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
           parent="@style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar tabs text styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTabText"
           parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

if you can translate farsi Language, use this :

[Customization Searchbar](http://www.beyamooz.com/android/292-%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B2%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%86-action-bar/1112-%D8%A2%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%B4-%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%84-%D8%AF%D9%87%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D9%87-action-bar#CustomBackground) 
and i also suggest you, read this :

[Customize the Android search view widget](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/pro-tip-customize-the-android-search-view-widget/)

Hope this help you.

Comment: Have you tried this with the latest AppCompat v21+?

Comment: That last link mentions that in order to get what I want I would have to hack it, with all associated risks. So not sure if that is what he wants but at least now I can share that info with him and if he wants to go ahead with it. Thanks for answering question.

Comment: @RekijanKileren Why would you mark this as correct then? That defeats the entire purpose of StackOverflow.com.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I wanted to know how to do it. The article linked describes how to do it but also says it is a hack and that you aren't supposed to do it because it doesnt guarantee it to work in later version. So my answer is to not do it and go back to the client and discuss this.

Comment: @RekijanKileren you completely do not understand how StackOverflow.com works. If the answer, answers your question and works and you have verified that it works, then you should mark it correct.

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer. Specifically: "`It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally, but not every user comes back to accept an answer, and of those who do, they may not change the accepted answer if a newer, better answer comes along later.`"